# ssh on remote host but switch user on local host running as root

Tags: ssh, remote, su

I have a script running as a root.
It ssh to remote host and run a script as user gol.
I have added ssh keys for the user(gol) to remote host.
But since the script is run as a root it still prompts for a password.
The script content is below

```
ssh gol@remotehost '/home/scripts/script1.sh'
```

so i changed the command to switch to local user before running the ssh command (because gol user has ssh keys added) but it fails.

```
su - gol -c ssh gol@remotehost '/home/scripts/script1.sh'
```

I need to run this as root as there are other scripts along with this script.

Comment: It is not clear: what you are trying to achieve, what you have tried, or what went wrong. (I have some ideas, but there are at least two possibilities) Please edit question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default SSH will try to use `root`'s private key because the client is running as root.  If you still want to run as root but want to use gol's private key then this might be possible because root has access to *everything*. 
 So to call ssh as root but use `gol`'s private key, you only need to tell ssh where the private key is.  I don't know your system, but the chances are that it's here:

```
/home/gol/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You can tell ssh which private key to use:

```
ssh -i /home/gol/.ssh/id_rsa gol@remotehost '/home/scripts/script1.sh'
```

---

Alternatively you can use the way you originally tried by quoting it properly:

```
su - gol -c "ssh gol@remotehost '/home/scripts/script1.sh'"
```

Comment: Thx. The second workaround works a treat.My sysadmin also suggested the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Please accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this working by adding quotes

`su - gol -c "ssh gol@remotehost '/home/scripts/script1.sh'"`

Thanks Philip for the update!

I haven't tried Philip workaround as I got this working by adding quotes.